# C# Filter a word with an undefined number of spaces between charachers

Tags: c#, filter

For exampe:

I can create a wordt with multiple spaces for example:

```
string example = "**example**";
List<string>outputs = new List<string>();
string example_output = "";
foreach(char c in example)
{
   example_putput += c + " ";
}
```

And then i can loop it to remve all spaces and add them to the outputs list,
The problem there is. I need it to work in scenario's where there are double spaces and more.

For example.

```
string text = "This is a piece of text for this **example**.";
```

I basicly want to detect AND remove '**example**'

But, i want to do that even when it says e xample, e  x   ample or example.

And in my scenaria, since its a spamfilter, i cant just replace the spaces in the whole sentence like below, because i'd need to .Replace( the word with the exact same spaces as the user types it in).

```
.Replace(" ", "");
```

How would i achieve this?

TLDR:
I want to filter out a word with multiple spaces combinations without altering any other parts of the line.

```
So example, e xample, e  x ample, e    x   a  m ple
```

becomes a filter word

I wouldn't mind a method which could generates a word with all spaces as plan b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that the problem is to ignore the spaces in the matchstring, but not touch them anywhere else in the string.

You could create a regular expression out of your matchword, allowing arbitrary whitespace between each character.

```
    // prepare regex. Need to do this only once for many applications.
    string findword = "example";
    // TODO: would need to escape special chars like * ( ) \ . + ? here.
    string[] tmp = new string[findword.Length];
    for(int i=0;i<tmp.Length;i++)tmp[i]=findword.Substring(i,1);
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex r = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(string.Join("\\s*",tmp));

    // on each text to filter, do this:
    string inp = "A text with the exa  mple word in it.";
    string outp;
    outp = r.Replace(inp,"");
    System.Console.WriteLine(outp);
```

Left out the escaping of regex-special-chars for brevity.

Comment: Thats awesome thats exactly what i ment!
Do you have any idea how i would use this method while also ignoring accents?

(So even ex  amplé) would get replaced?

I currently do that with:


private static string RemoveAccents(string s)
{
 Encoding destEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-8");

 return destEncoding.GetString(
  Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, destEncoding, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s)));
}

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex to achieve that:
`(e[\s]*x[\s]*a[\s]*m[\s]*p[\s]*l[\s]*e)`

[Link](https://regex101.com/r/j6dGF0/1)

[Dotnet Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/A4W0tS)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regex for that: `e\s*x\s*a\s*m\s*p\s*l\s*e`
`\s` means any whitespace character and the `*` means 0-n count of that whitespace.

Small snippet:

```
const string myInput = "e x ample";
var regex = new Regex("e\s*x\s*a\s*m\s*p\s*l\s*e");

var match = regex.Match(myInput);
if (match.Success)
{ 
   // We have a match! Bad word
}
```

Here the link for the regex: https://regex101.com/r/VFjzTg/1

Answer (score 1):

You can try *regular expressions*:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

....

// Having a word to find
string toFind = "Example";

// we build the regular expression
Regex regex = new Regex(
   @"\b" + string.Join(@"\s*", toFind.Select(c => Regex.Escape(c.ToString()))) + @"\b", 
   RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// Then we apply regex built for the required text:
string text = "This is a piece of text for this **example**. And more (e  X amp    le)";

string result = regex.Replace(text, "");

Console.Write(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
This is a piece of text for this ****. And more ()
```

**Edit:** if you want to ignore *diacritics*, you should modify regular expression:

```
  string toFind = "Example";

  Regex regex = new Regex(@"\b" + string.Join(@"\s*", 
    toFind.Select(c => Regex.Escape(c.ToString()) + @"\p{Lm}*")), 
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

and `Normalize` text before matching:

```
  string text = "This is a piece of text for this **examplé**. And more (e  X amp    le)";

  string result = regex.Replace(text.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD), "");
```

Comment: How would i use this combined with ignoring accents? so it can replace examplé

Comment: @thekguy: if you want to ignore diacritics, you should modify the regular expression and `Normalize` the text before matching / replacing. See my edit